# How to prevent HDIUTIL from opening a finder window when mounting a dmg?

Tags: mac, dmg-image

When I mount a DMG image with

```
hdiutil -noautoopen
```

and try to suppress the finder window with any and all command line arguments to HDIUTIL it still open's a Finder window. There must be a way to prevent this... am I wrong?

Comment: Since I´ve just tried `hdiutil attach -noautoopen /path/to/read-only.dmg` and it worked fine, could you please specify what kind of .dmg you are trying to open (read-only or not, which format)?

Comment: I'm specifically testing with this one... http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/mac/download/latest/AdobeAIR.dmg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Mountain Lion (10.8.3), none of the `-noautoopen` options worked.  The `-nobrowse` option does, though:

```
hdiutil attach -nobrowse /path/to/file.dmg
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

By default the Finder will always auto open *read only* images. Try to pass `-noautoopenro`!